# Is this function putting a space in?

Tags: function, asp-classic

We have a site which has a number of useful functions written by our third-party programmer, but lately, I've noticed that one of them seems to be putting a space in when it runs, but I can't seem to find where that might be in order to remove it.

The function is called "formatspecialcharacters". It's function is to take a string and look through it to change special characters from the string into HTML entities and is written as:

```
function formatspecialcharacters(stringtoformat)

formatspecialcharacters = ""

if isblank(stringtoformat) then exit function

stringtoformat = CStr(stringtoformat)
stringtoformat = Trim(stringtoformat)
fieldcontents = HTMLDecode(stringtoformat)

if Len(fieldcontents)>0 then
    for character_i = 1 to Len(fieldcontents)
        character_c = asc(mid(fieldcontents, character_i, 1))

        select case character_c
        case 174, 169 
            formatspecialcharacters = formatspecialcharacters & "<sup>" & chr(character_c) & "</sup>"
        case else
            formatspecialcharacters = formatspecialcharacters & chr(character_c)
        end select
    next
end if
end function
```

The other function running inside the one above (HTMLDecode) is written as:

```
Function HTMLDecode(sText)
sText = vbcrlf & vbtab & sText
    Dim I
    sText = Replace(sText, "&quot;", Chr(34))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&lt;"  , Chr(60))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&gt;"  , Chr(62))
    sText = Replace(sText, Chr(62)  , Chr(62) & vbcrlf & vbtab)
    sText = Replace(sText, "&amp;" , Chr(38))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&nbsp;", Chr(32))
    sText = Replace(sText, Chr(147), Chr(34)) 'smart quotes to proper quotes
    sText = Replace(sText, Chr(148), Chr(34))
    sText = Replace(sText, Chr(146), Chr(39)) 'smart apostrophe to proper apostrophe
    For I = 1 to 255
        sText = Replace(sText, "&#" & I & ";", Chr(I))
    Next
    HTMLDecode = sText
End Function
```

I think it's probably in the second function because when I use it like this:

```
<a href="<%=decendentdocumentformat_filename(j)%>"><%=formatspecialcharacters(decendentdocumentformat_label(j))%></a>
```

Where `"decendentdocumentformat_filename(j)" = "/example.html"` and `"formatspecialcharacters(decendentdocumentformat_label(j))" = "Web Page"`

In this example, when it's rendered, I have the link, followed by a space and then the label (in this case, `"Web Page"`) when it should just be the link then the label with no space between them.

Any help would be great.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not 100% sure I follow but if you were to;

```
<p><%=formatspecialcharacters("AAA") %><%=formatspecialcharacters("BBB") %></p>
```

You would see a space; `AAA BBB` because the 1st thing `HTMLDecode` does is prepend a carriage-return/line feed & tab to the input string, which the browser displays as a whitespace.

If you dont want the visible space remove `sText = vbcrlf & vbtab & sText`

(Also, the input is not trimmed after `HTMLDecode`, so if it were passed "`XXX&nbsp;`" you would have a trailing space)